# unity panel not working in 12.04?

Tags: unity, 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The auto-hide function of Launcher does not work well](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127704/the-auto-hide-function-of-launcher-does-not-work-well)

I just upgrade to 12.04 and when i want to launch the unity panel pointing the mouse on the left edge of the monitor it wont launch or it will take a long time to show up.