# How does the  launcher autohide work in 12.04?

Tags: launcher, autohide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The auto-hide function of Launcher does not work well](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127704/the-auto-hide-function-of-launcher-does-not-work-well)

I'm an Ubuntu noob who just upgraded to 12.04, and the launcher doesn't autohide anymore.  I went into Appearance and changed it there, and it collapsed as usual, but on mouseover, it didn't open. You could see a dropped shadow at the edge of the screen like it was trying to pop up?  But no dice.  Is this a known bug that will be corrected in the future or is this something I can fix on my own?  Thanks everyone for your time.