# Unity Launcher autohide not working correctly

Tags: unity, launcher, autohide

I don't know if this is a bug, but my Unity launcher autohide function stops working sometimes.

I have autohide enabled, and Launcher autohide works well most of the times, but now and then, the autohide stops working, and the Launcher is always present.

I go to system settings, and confirm that autohide is enabled.

I then disable the autohide, enable it again, and still autohide doesn't work.

Does anyone have the same problem? Is this a known bug?

Comment: i believe this is a bug in 12.04 and similar to this question http://askubuntu.com/q/127704/71679

Comment: Thanks, i read that article, but my problem is a bit different

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this happens to me, to solve press and hold the super key(Windows Key) for 5 seconds and autohide back to normal.

Comment: This is more of a workaround than a fix. But i will try it.

Comment: didn't work for me. is there a bug open for this?